# How to detect search has been turned off in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, share, charms-bar

What is a elegant way to detect if the user has turned off search for my app, so in case he tries to search my app, I can notify him that he has turned search off.

Comment: No need to downvote, it was a typo....

Answer (score 1):

If search is turned off for your app, you'd not be even getting notification for BeginSearch, so basically there is no event to start with.